# what do def self.up, def up, def self.down, def down mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone explain me please what the difference between the next things?

1. def self.up
2. def up
3. def self.down
4. def down

Comment: [This may help](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/migrations.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`self.up` and `up` contains the code that is ran by migrations when you do `rake db:migrate`. `self.up` is an older version of `up`. I'm not sure when they introduced this but until 3.0, they were using `self.up`.

`self.down` and `down` should contain the code that reverses the effect of the `up` methods.  so if you created a table on `up`, you should drop that table on `down`.  These methods are called when running `rake db:rollback`.

There's actually a new method on migrations called `change` which is usually used if it's easy for rails to determine the opposite of what you're doing like creating tables.

Answer (score 4):

`def self.up` is a class method (you can send it to the class: `Klass.up`), `def up` is a normal method (you can send it to an object). Same for down.